# Archive submission failed due to info.plist

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, plist

I encountered two problem while validating my project for it to be submitted to the app store:

[image]

The weird thing is that I do have an Info.plist in my project and the other thing is that I don't know what is the CFBundleVersion Key. What am I missing?

Comment: The errors may be related. Has your info.plist setting in Build Settings gone awry? Go to Build Settings, put info.plist into the search box, see if the setting (it'll be under Packaging) matches where your actual plist is...

Comment: I already uploaded my answer! Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't specified which was the bundle version of my project build. So I went into my info.plist and specified it:

[image]